# Listing data from MySQL database in drop down form not working?

Tags: php, mysql, html

For some reason this isn't working, even though I'm getting no errors. The drop down box just remains blank. I'm trying to use this to create a drop down list that shows what items the users currently owns. Thanks for reading.

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$action = $_GET['action'];
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<center><b> $row[name] </b><br><b>Uses: $row[uses]</b></center>";

if($action = "use")
{
if($row['type'] = "food")
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$mysqlq = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE owner = '$username'");
$item = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlq);

echo 
"
<form action='items.php?id=$id' name=itemform>
<select name='itemtouse'>
";
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlq)) 
{
echo "<option value=" . $item[name] . ">" . $item[name] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><input type=submit name=submit value=Use></input></form>";

}
else echo "This item doesn't exist.";
}
else echo "This item is not a food type.";
?>
```

Comment: If you do the query on MySQL console or phpMyAdmin SQL tab, does it return results there?

Comment: You're suppressing errors by using `@mysql_query()`, change it to `mysql_query()` and tell us, what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try without @ in mysql_query.
Because any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Also use all the variables inside ''. $row[name] as $row['name'].

**EDIT**

your have used the line `$item = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlq);`. this will loose the result.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$item[name]` to `$item['name']` where it is used.

And remove this unneeded (you make the assignment in while loop) row:

```
$item = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlq);
```